# What does "ad hoc" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, latin

I have come throw this word many many times but I couldn't get the meaning of it from the context.

It have appeared to me know in an online course on FOL (First Order logic ) when the instructor say:

> In the course, there are a few domains
>   that we will refer to repeatedly,
>   and some others that we'll just introduce on an ad hoc basis.

What does "ad hoc" mean in this context? Can you provide similar sentences to clarify the meaning more? Can it mean anything different in a different context? any examples?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ad-hoc

Answer (score 1):

*Ad hoc* is a Latin phrase that means "for this" or "for an specific purpose".

> In the course, there are a few domains that we will refer to
>   repeatedly, and some others that we'll just introduce **on an ad hoc
>   basis.**

In this case, **on an ad hoc basis** means **when/where necessary**

> In the course, there are a few domains that we will refer to
>   repeatedly, and some others that we'll just introduce **when/if
>   necessary**